# USB Hub requires "Scan for hardware changes" to detect my USB HDD

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I have two hubs (let's call them *D-Link* and *Amazon*) and two devices (a USB stick and a USB HDD), and I've noticed the following:

- Plug the USB stick in the D-Link hub: Detected immediately.
- Plug the USB stick in the Amazon hub: Detected immediately.
- Plug the USB HDD in the D-Link hub: Detected immediately.
- Plug the USB HDD in the Amazon hub: **Not detected.** A *scan for hardware changes* is required to detect the HDD:

[image: Scan for hardware changes screenshot]

How can I determine the cause for this issue? And can I fix it?

---

Notes (might be relevant or not):

- I actually have two USB HDDs (same build, Toshiba 2TB 2.5" USB 3.0), both behave as described above.
- The D-Link hub is USB 2.0 and the Amazon hub is USB 3.0, which is why I'd like to use the Amazon hub for my HDDs.
- The OS is Windows 10.
- Both hubs are powered.
- My PC did not have a native USB 3.0 port, so the Amazon hub is connected to a USB 3.0 PCI Express card.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the device manager and right click on the USB 3.0 option as shown in the image, then go to properties and disable the option "allow computer to turn off device to save power". This should fix your issue.

[image]